# Stopping time and filtration

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, stopping-times

My question is as follow:

Let $(\Omega,\cal{F}_\infty,\{\cal{F}_t\},\mathbb{P})$ be the filtred probability space. Further, denote $\cal{F}^*_t$ as the usual augmented filtration. Now, given a continuous $\cal{F}^*$-progressively measurable process $X$, we define: $H:=\inf\{t|X_t\leq 0\}$. Since $X$ is continuous, $H$ is an $\cal{F}^*$-stopping time. My question is whether there exists an $\cal F$-stopping time $\hat H$ such that $H=\hat H$ a.s. ? Thank you !

Comment: Yes this is Lemma 1.19 in Limit Theorems for Stochastic Processes by Jacod and Shiryaev. See [this related post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258730/showing-almost-sure-equality-of-two-stopping-times).

Comment: @StefanHansen: Thank you! That is indeed the same problem. I will read the reference.:)

Comment: @StefanHansen: I read Lemma 1.19 in the book by Jacod and Shiryaev. However, we need the conditiion that $\cal F_t$ is right continuous there...

Comment: Oh, I forgot that. My bad.